# Marked Seams not all cutting in UV Map

Tags: uv

I am trying to UV Unwrap the lower part of a mouth.  The teeth have been outlined with seams to remove them.  I want to be able to Texture Paint them separately from the rest of the mesh.  Most of the teeth gave no problem but the front four do not want to detach from the rest of the mesh.  Removing Doubles found none and I can not find any other modeling problems.
Any suggestions on fixes that can be tried?

[image]

[BLEND FILE](https://we.tl/t-iNSAWVIs3t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird because I've seamed the other teeth, unwraped with the first unwrap option (*Unwrap*), and it worked perfectly, so you must do something wrong somewhere, what option are you choosing?

[image]

Comment: Weird indeed.  When I opened the file again today it was suddenly working again using Unwrap.  Thanks for looking.